# Required Input Field + Onlick Button request

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I am trying to make my input field required.

```
<form name="myForm" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
    <center><button id="process2"  type="submit">Continue</button> </center>
</form>
```

When I have the above portion it works, however I need it to work whenever I have my `button` containing a `onlick` event. `<button id="process2"  type="submit" onclick="move()">Continue</button>` how can I go about doing this?

The issue is currently - The `onclick` request will fire, and it'll prompt the required option, however the onclick request should not fire unless the required option is populated.

Comment: Rather than ```onclick="doSomething()"``` in input tag. Place it in form tag like ```<form name="myform" method="post" onsubmit="doSomething()">```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the `onclick` , you should listen for the form's `submit`, and call `move()` inside it

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('submitted');
  
  move();
});

function move() {
  console.log('moving ..');
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
    <button id="process2"  type="submit">Continue</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just simply fire the move function but wrap your deserted effect inside if statement that will check if input is empty or not...

```js
function move() {
  element = document.getElementById("username").value;
  if (element === "") {
    console.log("input wasnt populated do something");
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
  <center><button id="process2" type="submit" onclick="move()">Continue</button> </center>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can listen the submit event on form like then call move function to redirect to other page or whatever logic you want

```
$(document).on('submit','form',function(){
   event.preventDefault();


// call move function here , move();
});
```